# JSF - p:ajax listener asking for parameters netBeans/primefaces

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces

Versions:
NetBeans: 7.2.1
PrimeFaces: 3.5.3
GlassFish: 3.1.2
JDK 1.6

I've been trying to find related issues and have found topics that are close, but not quite what I'm looking for. I'm trying to do something similar to the [p:schedule demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf) from PrimeFaces ShowCase where I want a dialog to appear showing the details of the event clicked.

I think the issue is coming from calling the listener method from the backing bean. When I go to type in the listener method in the p:ajax tag, NetBeans forces me to pass in a parameter like:

```
listener="#{cmodel.onEventSelect(e)}"
```

which I don't think is necessary as I don't have a value to pass in anyways.

I'm thinking either:

1. Something is up with NetBeans that doesn't recognize the method as a listener. (Since i keep seeing multiple examples of people calling the method without needing to pass a parameter.)

or

1. I'm not registering the method as a listener properly in the Model.

Also, I have directly copied and pasted the demo from the ShowCase into a project and it didn't work which is making me lean more towards an issue with NetBeans. (that is, the dialog appears but with no information on the event that was selected)

So to summarize; events are showing up as they should on the schedule itself, I just cant get the dialog to show the event details of the event that was selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

View Layer:

```
<h:form>
    <p:schedule id="nelsonsSchedule" value="#{cmodel.scheduleModel}" showHeader="true"
                leftHeaderTemplate="none" rightHeaderTemplate="prev, next today"
                draggable="false" timeZone="UTC" styleClass="schedule">                       
                    <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{cmodel.onEventSelect}"
                            update="eventDialog eventDetails" oncomplete="eventDialog.show()"/>                       
                </p:schedule>

                <p:dialog id="eventDialog" widgetVar="eventDialog" header="EventDetails">
                    <p:panel id="eventDetails">
                        <h:outputLabel value="#{cmodel.selectedEvent.title}" />
                    </p:panel>
                </p:dialog>                   
            </h:form>
```

Backing Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "cmodel")
```

@SessionScoped
public class CalendarModel implements Serializable {

```
private ScheduleModel scheduleModel;
private List<ScheduleEvent> allScheduledGames;
private DefaultScheduleEvent gameEvent;
public ScheduleEvent selectedEvent;
List<Game> allGames;
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public CalendarModel() {

}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    allScheduledGames = new ArrayList<ScheduleEvent>();
    allGames = new ArrayList<Game>();       

    allGames = em.createNamedQuery("Game.findAll").getResultList();

    /*create list of games to put into the ScheduleModel*/
    for (int i = 0; i < allGames.size(); i++) {

        gameEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(allGames.get(i).getOpponent() +
                    "\n\n\n" + allGames.get(i).getTimeOfGame(),
                    allGames.get(i).getDateOfGame(),
                    allGames.get(i).getDateOfGame());

        if(allGames.get(i).getHomeAway().equals("away")){
            gameEvent.setStyleClass("away");
        } else{
            gameEvent.setStyleClass("home");               
        }

        gameEvent.setData(allGames.get(i));           
        allScheduledGames.add(gameEvent);
    }/*end for*/

    scheduleModel = new DefaultScheduleModel(allScheduledGames);

}/*end init()*/

public void onEventSelect (SelectEvent e) {
    selectedEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    selectedEvent = (ScheduleEvent) e.getObject();       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into the same issue - It was NetBeans. I upgraded to 7.3 and don't have the problem anymore. Although another has come up where itellisense doesn't recognize a hashmap from the backing bean, but that's for another question.